# TFS Extension LocalStorage

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to port an application which uses localstorage to store values between sessions. Looking at vss-web-extension-sdk's VSS.SDK.js, it looks like TFS runs extensions in a sandbox which shims in a localstorage replacement, which works well enough within a session, but nothing set in shimmedLocalStorage persists when the page or iframe is refreshed.

Is this a bug, or is shimmedLocalStorage not meant to persist?

It's crucial that this application is able to store user settings and data, is there any other way to do this in a TFS extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS Extension Data Storage on Project Scope Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553629/vsts-extension-data-storage-on-project-scope-level)

Comment: Do you use TFS or VSTS?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I'm using both but I only run into this problem with TFS. The extension actually works perfectly with VSTS and is able to access localstorage just fine.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Version 16.122.27102.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS extensions have the ability to store user preferences and complex data structures directly on Microsoft-provided infrastructure.

There are two ways to interact with the data storage service: REST APIs or a Microsoft-provided client service available as part of the VSS SDK. It is highly recommended that extension developers use the provided client service APIs, which provide a convenient wrapper over the REST APIs.

Details refer to [Data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage).